# How to display frames when I use the MediaCodec for encoding

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, egl

I just follow the http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt which use MediaCodec for encoding frames from camera preview.
Now I can get the data(byte[]) from encoding, but how can I display the preview when I encoding?
I canot catch what he says:

```
        // If you want to have two EGL contexts -- one for display, one for
    // recording --
    // you will likely want to defer instantiation of CodecInputSurface
    // until after the
    // "display" EGL context is created, then modify the eglCreateContext
    // call to
    // take eglGetCurrentContext() as the share_context argument.
```

Does it means that I must draw the data to an EGL context myself?
If it is, what should I do next?

Comment: The "Show + capture camera" and "continuous capture" activities in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) both display and record video from the camera.  The former uses GLSurfaceView and two EGL contexts, the latter uses SurfaceView and a single context.  Both rely on features available in API 18+.  You can also just convert the byte[] from YUV to an RGB Bitmap and render that.

Comment: Thanks fadden for helping me in MediaCodec twice ：） It's very kind of you